# NoClassDefFoundError only for API 22

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm developing a project that used to work fine for APIs 23 and 22, however, something happens that as soon as the app starts it crashes (activity don't even get to be loaded) - only for API 22, for API 23 it works fine. The log don't helped me a lot and I'm running out of ideas of what might have caused this error to occur. The class that it complains is the App class defined in the manifest. Below are some code that might be useful to analyse:

### Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="br.com.gogame">

<application
    android:name=".commons.infra.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="DATABASE"
        android:value="gogame.db" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="VERSION"
        android:value="27" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="QUERY_LOG"
        android:value="false" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
        android:value="br.com.gogame.model" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".view.activities.ActivityLogin"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

### App Class (the one it complains that doesn't exists):

public class App extends com.orm.SugarApp {

```
private static App mApp = null;
private static MainComponent component;
private static RestTemplate mRequestService = new RestTemplate();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mApp = this;
    component = DaggerMainComponent
            .builder()
            .utilModule(new UtilModule(this))
            .postmanModule(new PostmanModule(mRequestService))
            .controllerModule(new ControllerModule())
            .build();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EventListener.class);
    startService(intent);
}

public static Application getApplication() {
    return mApp;
}

public static Context getContext() {
    if (mApp == null) {
        return new Application();
    }
    return mApp.getApplicationContext();
}

public static MainComponent getComponent() {
    return component;
}

public static boolean isApplicationInBackground() {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mApp.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(mApp.getApplicationContext().getPackageName())) {
                        isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(mApp.getApplicationContext().getPackageName())) {
            isInBackground = false;
        }
    }

    return isInBackground;
}
```

}

### LogCat:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: br.com.gogame, PID: 31071             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application br.com.gogame.commons.infra.App: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "br.com.gogame.commons.infra.App" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/br.com.gogame-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/br.com.gogame-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                               at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:563)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4611)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
                                                            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "br.com.gogame.commons.infra.App" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/br.com.gogame-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/br.com.gogame-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1003)
                                                               at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:558)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4611) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378) 
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
                                                            Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.gogame.commons.infra.App
                                                               at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                    ... 13 more
                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

### Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    compileOptions.incremental = false

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "br.com.gogame"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    renderscriptTargetApi 23
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

```
// GOOGLE LIBRARIES
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_version"
compile "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.1'
provided 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.1'
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

// KOTLIN
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

// ANKO
compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:$anko_version"
compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:$anko_version"
compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4:$anko_version"
compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"

// APACHE LIBRARIES
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.0-alpha3'

// OWN THIRD LIBRARIES
compile 'br.com.instachat:emoji-library:1.0.8'
compile 'br.com.edsilfer:kiwi:1.0.16'


// THIRD PART LIBRARIES
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.github.vajro:MaterialDesignLibrary:1.6'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.0@aar'
compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.3'
compile 'com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.6@aar'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.5'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile "com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.6.6@aar"
compile 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter:1.5.6@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:5.6.6@aar'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.15'
compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:1.5.0'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.5'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.0.2'
compile 'com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms:view-pager-transforms:1.2.32@aar'
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'

provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Did you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to kick yourself..

in manifest package name is missing the br at the beginning it should be:
br.com.gogame.commons.infra.App

you instead have it as .com.gogame.commons.infra.App which will not work and hence the class not found error

Comment: I don't think so, ```package="br.com.gogame"``` is declared at the second line of the manifest and in the logcat it points out to the right path!